# angular 5 select IE no value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am currently having an issue with Angular.X (Tested with A5 & A6). It appears when using a "Select" within the html, Internet Explorer doesn't bind appropriately with ngModel. I've tested with Chrome and Edge and they work fine, When trying to use this combination in edge- the select never gets set as its default value (The value that is assigned within the model/property its bound to). So the page will load with empty values in the select. I've tried searching but have not had any luck finding an answer how to fix this. 9/10 of the posts I find when searching for this are related to AngularJS. Which always makes troubleshooting fun!

Here is a bit of the code as to how I am doing this:

HTML:

```
// The repeater is up top somewhere and looks like this:
// <tr *ngFor="let i of this.imgArr">

<td class="ImageCell">
    <select [disabled]="this.ApplyingChanges" [(ngModel)]="i.ImageType" class="form-control" (change)="this.ChangeInput(i)">
        <option>Part</option>
        <option>Model</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

TS Class:

```
export class PartImage{
    public ImageType = 'Part';
```

The above code is broken up to show what matters. 
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I actually resolved this. 
After tinkering around, I discovered: With Edge and Chrome, an "option" is not required to have the attribute "value" and uses the label by default. With Internet Explorer this is not true and requires that attribute (Or ngValue) to work correctly.